# Use JavaScript-Variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I´m having a normal JavaScript-function and want to use the Variable (myVar) also in my jQuery Code - is this possible? and how?:

```
<a onclick="showtitle(abctitle);" href="#">Testlink</a>

<script>
function showtitle(myVar) {
    myTitle = myVar;    
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(myTitle); //I would like to alert "abctitle"
};
</script>
```

Comment: what is this I dont even

Comment: why is that variable in your HTML code in the first place?

Comment: how you get myTitle on your page load without click on a

Comment: @Sarfaraz with the current code, he can't

Comment: i think he has to improve his code first

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, don't mix DOM0 inline event handlers with jQuery.  Separate your markup and your logic.

If you use a `data-` attribute you can put your variable's content in your HTML, and then extract that in the event handler:

```
<a id="test" data-foo="mytitle" href="#">Testlink</a>
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).data('foo'));
    }
});
```

In this code the `alert` won't appear until the link is actually clicked on, of course.

Comment: this looks good, but I really want the showtitle()-function outside jQuery if possible!

Comment: @Marc why - what are you really trying to achieve?  What do you mean by "outside jQuery"?  jQuery is still _just javascript_.

Comment: because I start the showtitle()-function from a panorama player and this one needs the normal javascript-function: http://krpano.com/docu/js/#top

Comment: then you need to expand your question.  Your existing code makes zero sense - you can't expect the `document.ready` handler to have access to a variable that doesn't get set until after you've clicked the link!

Answer (score 1):

I believe @Alnitak has a great answer. But if you are just looking to solve the question you asked, wrap abctitle in single quotes and make `myTitle` a global variable:

```
<a onclick="showtitle('abctitle 2');" href="#">Testlink</a>

<script>
myTitle = "abctitle";

function showtitle(myVar) {
    myTitle = myVar;    
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(myTitle); //I would like to alert "abctitle"
});
</script>
```

Also, your document ready function was missing its closing parenthesis `)`

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CbhxY/

**UPDATE**

Working example on jsfiddle did not work so well. Try this: http://jsbin.com/ohedab/1/

The JS Bin example also adds the `alert` call in the showtitle function.

Comment: same comment as I made to mattytommo - the document.ready handler will get called automatically (with `myTitle` still undefined) before the `onclick` handler can ever be invoked.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: showtitle is not defined (onclick on link)

Comment: I get that too, locally it works in a fresh html file...maybe an issue with jsfiddle and the way I'm declaring the fx?

Comment: @shanabus it's because jsfiddle has automatically wrapped your code in an `onload` handler, preventing `showtitle` from becoming a global variable (as is required by DOM0 inline event handlers).

Answer (score 0):

you can do with this

```
function showtitle(abctitle){
  alert(myTitle); //I would like to alert "abctitle"
}
```